# Roles gestion with asp:hyperlink menu

Tags: asp.net

I have a little problem, I just made a menu with some asp:hyperlink structured in list.
I just wonder if it is possible to filter some of these asp:hyperlink in relation with "roles" defined in the web.sitemap?

For example :

```
      <ul id="topnav">
        <li>Dep
            <span>
                <asp:HyperLink  Text="testing one" NavigateUrl="/DEP/ENC/Dep_Enc.aspx" runat="server">Encode </asp:HyperLink>
                <asp:HyperLink Text="testing two" NavigateUrl="/DEP/ENC/Dep_Enc_D.aspx" runat="server">Nouveau contrat</asp:HyperLink>

...


    <siteMapNode >
    <siteMapNode url="/DEP/Dep_Ac.aspx" title="Dép" >
      <siteMapNode url="/DEP/ENC/Dep_Enc.aspx" roles="ALL" >
        <siteMapNode url="/DEP/ENC/Dep_Enc_D.aspx" roles="ADMIN"/>
...
```

so is it possible to make disappear test two if user is not "admin"? 
Thanks for help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always add a `runat="server"` attribute, along with an `id` to any classic html tag. In your case, you could add this to the `<li>` or `<span>`as needed:

```
<ul id="topnav">
  <li runat="server" id="adminLinks">Dep
     <span>
       <asp:HyperLink  Text="testing one" NavigateUrl="/DEP/ENC/Dep_Enc.aspx" runat="server">Encode </asp:HyperLink>
       <asp:HyperLink Text="testing two" NavigateUrl="/DEP/ENC/Dep_Enc_D.aspx" runat="server">Nouveau contrat</asp:HyperLink>

...
```

Then, in your code behind, use the `Visible` property to hide it (it won't even be renderer to html):

```
if (!User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
  adminLinks.Visible = false;
}
```